# Changing logo when signed in

Tags: views, theming

In page.tpl.php, the logo section is handled as:

```
<?php if ($logo): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When user signs in, I want logo to change from `logo.png` to `inner_logo.png`

I can track where `$logo` comes from and add an if statement like `<?php if($user->uid <=0) { $logo = "logo.png" } else { ... ?>`

But would this be the correct practice? Is there a more practical Drupal way?

edit:

```
/* Override or insert variable into the pre-process_template*/
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (user_is_logged_in()) {
        $variables['logo'] = (drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/images/inner_logo.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, every .tpl.php has what is called a "preprocess" function.  The default one for page.tpl.php is [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7).  This sets up the variables that are available in the template.  Other modules and themes can have their own; then don't replace each other, rather, they all run in a [defined order](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7).

So, you would add in a preprocess function for your theme's template.php like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME');

    $variables['logo'] = file_create_url($path . '/images/inner_logo.png');
  }
}
```

This will check to see if the user is logged in using the proper API call (program to the interface not the implementation), and then change the logo variable to a new path from within your theme.  Just make sure you clear the Drupal caches from admin/config/development/performance first so the function gets picked up.

Comment: On the website that you shared, it states that `template_preprocess_page()` function is located in `includes/theme.inc, line 2539`. But I couldnt locate to it?

Comment: It's there; it's line 2532 in the current version in git.  You wouldn't edit this directly, though.  You would make your own version in your own theme.

Comment: use `template.php`

Comment: I made the change here; `function theme_get_setting($setting_name, $theme = NULL) {` and it worked. Please review the original question edited codes. Is this acceptable or would you still recommend me to use `template.php` or the `template_preprocess_page()` function?

Comment: @Efe Editing your question with your solution isn't the StackExchange way.  If you have another solution, you can answer your own question.  To answer your question above, editing includes/theme.inc is [bad](https://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core);  use template.php

Comment: I have then misunderstood the article on the link that you have shared. I thought I had to make a change in the `includes/theme.inc` file since `template_preprocess_page()` is located there.

Comment: So I now removed my changes in `theme.inc` file and put the code that you have written inside `template.php`. But the if statement stopped working now?

Comment: @Efe  Do a little googling on preprocess functions and template.php.  That should shed some light on the matter, and my answer will start to make sense.

Comment: Strangely, I deleted the theme, reinstalled it with the new template.php and it worked!